# How do I make generic memoization in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

I want to define a generic memoizing wrapper in Crystal.
I have the following crystal code:

```
  module Scalar(T)
    abstract def value: T
  end

  class ScSticky(T)
    include Scalar(T)

    def initialize(sc : Scalar(T))
      @sc = sc
      @val = uninitialized T
    end

    def value: T
      @val ||= @sc.value
    end
  end
```

In other words I want `ScSticky` to call the underlying `Scalar(T)` only once and return the cached output for all subsequent calls.
However, the above approach doesn't work if `T` is `Int32`

For instance, when wrapping this class

```
class ScCounter
  include Scalar(Int32)

  def initialize
      @val = 100
  end

  def value: Int32
    @val += 1
    @val
  end
end
```

`ScSticky(ScCounter.new).value` will always be equal to `0` (as I understand it, because the `unitialized Int32` is actually initialized with 0 value)

I would highly appreciate some help with this problem

Upd: It seems that the proper way to implement this is using `nil` , however I have problems with understanding how exactly such implementation should look. I also want to be able to memoize `.value` method even if it returns `nil` (In other words, if the `T` is a nilable type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an unsafe feature "`uninitialized`", which means, "keep whatever was there in memory previously" (in theory the value is random and possibly invalid, in practice you often end up with 0 anyway -- but it's still not guaranteed at all).
The short story about the `uninitialized` feature is *please never use it*.

This behavior wouldn't surprise you if you wrote `@val = 0` -- and that's kinda what you wrote.

You must define `@val : T? = nil` -- to make it nilable (have this separate possible value of `nil`, which is its own type - `Nil`).
You may have thought that `unitialized` brings `nil` into the picture, but it definitely doesn't.

---

In response to your comment about also including `nil` into possible values, here's a full solution, which, instead of Nil, uses a unique "sentinel" struct, that the user can never create.

```
module Scalar(T)
  abstract def value: T
end
 
private struct Sentinel
end
 
class ScSticky(T)
  include Scalar(T)
 
  @val : T | Sentinel = Sentinel.new
  
  def initialize(@sc : Scalar(T))
  end
 
  def value: T
    val = @val
    if val.is_a?(Sentinel)
      @val = @sc.value
    else
      val
    end
  end
end
 
class ScCounter
  include Scalar(Int32)
 
  def initialize
    @val = 100
  end
 
  def value: Int32
    @val += 1
  end
end
 
sc = ScSticky.new(ScCounter.new)
 
p! sc.value #=> 101
p! sc.value #=> 101
```

Comment: Yeah, I get it. But how do I implement this using `nils`? I seem to have problems with ensuring the compiler that the value I am returning is not nil. I also want to be able to cache the method event if it returns nil

Comment: Regarding "I also want to be able to cache the method event if it returns nil", I recommend to fully and thoroughly read the language reference. Here in particular seems this part is relevant: https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/if_var.html#limitations